# redirection on MYMODULE_user_register_form_alter

Tags: drupal, hook-form-alter

ive been searching a lot and found a lot of post also but cant still make my code works. i dont really know the problem anymore, it is so hard to debug.

so i have this code module `send_xml.module`

i used the `hook_form_FORMID_alter`, it was like

```
function send_xml_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'send_xml_submit_function';
}

function send_xml_submit_function($form, &$form_state){
    $email = $form_state['values']['mail'];
    $password = $form_state['values']['pass'];

    unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
    unset($form['#redirect']); 
    $form_state['redirect'] = array(
        'myurl',
         array(
            'query' => array(
                 'email' => $email,
                 'password' => $password,
             ),
         ),
    );
}
```

i want this to redirect to an external link with the values from the regsitration form... but i can't get it to work... its my 3rd day now at is giving me a lot of pain really...

please help anyone please... it will be a big help. thank you very much! :)

Comment: You are using the drupal registration form to send data to another site? Why use the drupal registration form at all?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML of the form? Other sites seem to reference #action instead of #submit

Comment: @2pha because i need to run the `myurl` so that it will register to my javaWebApp, the url contains the email and password. so the javaWebApp will just `$_GET` the data it needed, then saved it to the database.

Comment: @drnugent

`<input class="username form-text required" type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="60">`

here is one of the input fields, its too long if i put all the HTML..what do you mean by your comment?

here's the submit button
`<input class="ctools-modal-ctools-ajax-register-style form-submit ajax-processed" type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Create new account">`

Comment: You mentioned that your code does not work, but didn't give any symptoms. By describing the symptoms and editing your comment to include the full form HTML you will help us troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

In your submit method, give url instead of array using url() function to set redirect value. Currently you are giving array in $form_state['redirect]. Try following:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = url('myurl', array(
    'query' => array (
                 'email' => $email, 
                 'password' => $password)
     )
);
```